# Mercurial - determining if a merge is required from remote repo

Tags: mercurial, merge

We have two repositories: `myapp` and `myapp-1.1`.  We merge myapp-1.1 into myapp.

To see if there are changes in 1.1 that need to be merged I do this:

```
cd c:\myapp     (local clone)
hg fetch        (fetch from remote myapp repo)
hg in ssh://hg/myapp-1.1    (see what needs to be merged in from remote 1.1 repo)
```

This works - but is there a better way?  Is there a way to do this without requiring the local myapp clone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mercurial can't do much with remote repositories except for some variant of pushing to, or pulling from them.

As such, anything you want to ask Mercurial to do has to be done with a local clone.

So no, there is no way to have Mercurial check if two remote repositories needs to be merged.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with having local clone, exactly?

If you want to isolate all operations on machine the repo is located, you could do the following:

```
$ ssh $hg_box
$ cd myapp; hg in /myapp-1.1
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with local clone, just looking to avoid it.  I don't have access to go onto the box where the remote repositories exist.  So I have to have a local clone where I do `hg fetch` before I can see if a merge is required (per my question).  It would be nice to not have to do that...

Answer (score 1):

This may seem like the obvious response, but since Mercurial is a completely distributed source control system, and each repo is stand alone, is it possible for you to actually go to the box that has myapp and fetch directly from myapp-1.1? I know most dev teams keep some kind of centralized repository, but that doesn't preclude the use of Mercurial directly from the box that you have as your 'central' repository. It's all still local and remote repositories.

This assumes that you want to fully merge myapp and myapp1.1. Otherwise, pretty much by definition of what you're doing, you have to clone myapp to another full repository, then merge it with myapp-1.1.

Comment: Good suggestion, but no I don't have access to the remote repo box.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming neither the remote repo nor the local repo allows multiple heads per branch, this command should tell if the local repo has the head of the remote repo at a given branch:

```
hg log -r $( hg in -b branch_name -n -l1 -q --template "{node}\n" )
```

If local repo doesn't have that changeset, but has outgoing changesets at "branch_name", then typically it should be an indicator that merge is needed.